# Class libary portable ios, android and windows can't change other framework to install jsonConfig

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I created a project type class library portable ios, android and windows.
it framework version is 4.5, but this version I can't install jsonConfig.
I trying to change for framework version 4.5.2 to install jsonConfig, but when I change always return 4.5 version.

which other way to install jsonConfig?

Comment: Tu veux utiliser les composants json dans ton projet? c'est ça l'inquiétude?

Comment: Oui, je veux utiliser JSON Config dans une bibliothèque de classe spécifie le Xamarin pour Android, iOS et Windows.
Désolé pour mon français.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to consume json

https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net

Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: Json.net and Newtonsoft, I can't use with config.
Right now I think to use a xml file